# Is it possible to exhaust your dynamic port range by rapidly sending a lot of HTTP requests to localhost?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, localhost, loopback

Consider the following scenario. I have a server application and a client application on the same machine. My client very rapidly sends a lot of HTTP requests to my server, and new requests appear more quickly than old ones are processed.

If client and server applications were deployed on different machines we would eventually run out of ports in dynamic port range on the client machine. But is this also true for localhost connections via loopback? Or does loopback somehow "optimize" sockets, so this problem is not applicable?

I'm mainly interested in Windows-specific answers, but Linux-specific information could also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD: definitely yes.

On Windows: probably yes. Your TCP state is a tuple of your IP address and your port. If you choose to connect to local host it's still within your connection table and handled *exactly like* an outside connection. It was a problem I already ran into back in the Windows 7 area and I'm not aware that it has been changed since then. It will take you a lot of connections dough.